# How to access object slicing?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
public:
int i;
int j;

};

class B : public A
{
public:
int k;

};

main()
{
  A *a = new B;

}
```

is it possible to access slicing data?

Comment: there is no object slicing here. Can you be more specific? what is meant by *accessing* object slicing?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c for a good discussion on this

Comment: @Naveen: But unless you, as a programmer keep of track, remembering that it is a B, there is no way to know that `*a` also contains a B part, so it is as good as sliced.

Comment: Instead of recommending it to be closed (as not a question) why not help OP fix the terminology, because the intent of the question seems quite obvious (how to access members in a derived class through a pointer to base class?)

Answer (score 1):

Slicing looks like this:

```
struct B {
    virtual ~B() { }
};
struct D : public B {
    int a, b;
};

int main()
{
    D der;
    B bas(der);  // der is sliced!
}
```

There is no way for the `B bas` object to see the extra information of `D der` even though the information is there. We say that that extra information got "sliced off". `bas` can't access any of it because the standard allows `D` objects to be stored in memory (almost) arbitrarily, for [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) purposes. The only guarantee you have for `der` is that its first data member's address is the same as the object's address.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is to down-cast the pointer.

```
static_cast<B*>(a)->k = 10;
```

The premise is that you actually **know for sure** that at this point in code `a` always refers to an instance of `B`, because, for the lack of virtual functions and a vtable, there is no way for the language to test at run-time, if that cast is valid or not.

---

Technically, nothing is sliced yet, you just can't access it otherwise because for all the compiler knows, you have a pointer to an object of type A, and this is a case where you simply must know better.

---

IMO, if you only use inheritance to add data fields to a class that is there only to hold data, you shouldn't generally be messing with pointers to a base class at all.

If you are showing only part of the code and you do have virtual functions in there, use `dynamic_cast` instead, because then it is possible to check if the cast is valid.